# PDO error displaying query results: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, ajax

So I'm trying AJAX for the first time and I'm stoked! I have a file called ajaxtest1.html and it just has a simple text box where a mileage is entered and then passed on to another file where it receives it, plonks it into the query and sends back the result. Here's ajaxtest1...

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
var miles = document.getElementById('miles').value;
var queryString = "?miles=" + miles;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "results.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
// ]]></script>
<form name="myForm">Miles: <input id="miles" type="text" /> <br /> <br /> <input onclick="ajaxFunction()" value="Query MySQL" type="button" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in results.php. I have

```
<?php
$hostname = 'host';


$username = 'user';

$password = 'password';


$miles = $_GET['miles'];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=ratetable", $username, $password);
    echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage <= :miles ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bindParam(':miles', $miles, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {

    // get the rowcount
    $numrows = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($numrows > 0) {
    // match
    // Fetch rows
      $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
    else {
    // no rows
    }
   }

$display_string = "<table>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Mileage</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Rate Per Mile</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Inbound skid rate</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Inbound truckload</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

while($row_object = array($miles)){
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<td>$row[mileage]</td>";
$display_string .= "<td>$row[ratepermile]</td>";
$display_string .= "<td>$row[skidinbound]</td>";
$display_string .= "<td>$row[truckinbound]</td>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

   }
    echo "Query: " . $stmt . "<br />";
    $display_string .= "</table>";
    echo $display_string;


/*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

[UPDATED]

I'm pretty new to using PDO (well, PHP in general and I'm picking it up.)

I am getting the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string
```

and this is happening on the line that reads:

```
echo "Query: " . $stmt . "<br />";
```

It's connecting to the database fine. Can someone please tell me what could be wrong? I kind of winged it when it came to trying to form the PDO statement so it would handle my query and it's choking on the last bit.

I've updated the PHP code to show you what I've tried.

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: There is no question in this. Are you just trying to say how excited you are about AJAX?

Comment: Well, I thought I had indicated what the problem was but you're right. I should have posed a question so I did that now. Thanks. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: We still need more info. What error messages are you getting? What isn't working?

Comment: Did you see the content just below? No errors. Just a form and no response. I don't know if AJAX is sending it and tried Vik's suggestion to see if I could get a response code. I'm on GoDaddy and I'm starting to wonder if AJAX is supported. I can't imagine why it wouldn't be though. Is my query string right in my AJAX code?

Comment: I just updated my question. Connects to the database fine but getting an error on the line that reads echo "Query: " . $stmt . "<br />";". The error is "Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string." What could the problem be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your results.php file:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage <= :miles ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindParam(':miles', $miles, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You could remove the cast from this line:

```
$miles = (int) $_GET['miles'];
```

Comment: Can you do this: `if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status ==200){ alert(ajaxRequest.responseText) ...` and check if you get any response...use console.log or alert statements at different points to debug your message. If you are not getting anything in alert. try checking output of php file before you echo it back to ajax

Comment: you can also add an `else{alert()}` to your `if{}` to see if you get any responses at all

Comment: You mean put that in my html file?

Comment: yes in the block containing: `ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange `

Comment: Did that. Nothing happened. Here's what that block looks like now:  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status ==200){
                        alert(ajaxRequest.responseText)
                }
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
   document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
  }
 }
 var miles = document.getElementById('miles').value;
 var queryString = "?miles=" + miles;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "results.php" + queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

Comment: Is it possible that AJAX isn't supported on GoDaddy? Should I use jQuery instead?

Comment: IMHO AJAX would definitely be supported by GoDaddy. jQuery and AJAX are two different technologies addressing two different things(although they could be used in tandem to achieve a common goal...getJSON() for example)... you might want to ensure that your php is returning results of your query as expected..

Comment: It's connecting to the database fine but not echoing back results. I do have records and did a query where I know what the answer should be. It now appears to not be passing the row to the part where it's passed back to the div.

Answer (score 0):

"Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string." Means exactly what it says. The $stmt variable is a PDO object, and you are trying to echo it like it is a string. You can't echo an object, just like you can't just echo an array.

Replace this line

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage <= ? ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1');
```

With this:

```
$query_text = 'SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage <= ? ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query_text);
```

And then replace this line

```
echo "Query: " . $stmt . "<br />";
```

With this

```
echo "Query: " . $query_text . "<br />";
```

Comment: Hi there, well, that did help except it didn't like the ? so I changed it to $miles in the query_text statement. After I changed that, no errors but it's not displaying a row.